# (a && b) versus (a and b)

Tags: ruby

Given :

```
a=true
b=false
```

why can I do :

```
puts [a && b, a || b]  #[false, true]
```

but not

```
puts [a and b, a or b]
```

syntax error, unexpected keyword_and, expecting ']'
puts [a and b, a or b]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the operator precedence for the comma is higher than "and" but lower than &&.

Putting parenthesis around the elements works:

```
[(a and b), (a or b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to simply group the terms to avoid precedence issues:

```
puts [(a and b),(a or b)]
```